# What is a good tool to calculate IRR of my entire portfolio?

Tags: software

I use Mint to aggregate all of my accounts and get a snapshot of what my financial health is like, but I need something more powerful to calculate IRR and other metrics. What are some tools the community uses?

Comment: Tried MS excel ??

Comment: MS Excel doesn't automatically import my bank info

Comment: Write a macro to import all your data onto excel. Shouldn't be a big bummer.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Sheehan, I believe Schwab provides this info.  None of the online free portfolio managers I know of gives you this info.  The now defunct MS Money used to have this.

The best thing to do is to use a spreadsheet.  Or you could use the one I use.  http://www.moneycone.com/did-you-beat-the-market-mr-investor/ .

(disclaimer: that's my blog)